# Inputing values to structs

Tags: c++, struct, cin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct broker {
    int teller, nevner;
};

int main () {
    int i;
    broker brok1, brok2, brok3;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cin >> brok[i].teller >> brok[i].nevner;
    }
}
```

I am trying to input values for three **structs** `brok1`, `brok2` and `brok3`. But I´m getting an error saying `brok[i]` doesn't exist. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access i-th element of an **array** here: `brok[i]` but you haven't declared any array in your code, only 3 separate `broker` variables (`brok1`, `brok2`, `brok3`).

Change `broker brok1, brok2, brok3;` to `broker brok[3];` and it should work fine.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, change `broker brok1, brok2, brok3;` to `broker brok[3];` to create an actual array. You can't access variables indirectly by name in C++.